# Exporting image from Earth Engine results in black page and black TIFF file

Tags: google-earth-engine

```
Map.addLayer(geometry);
Map.centerObject(geometry, 3);

function maskL8sr(image) {
 // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
 var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
// Get the pixel QA band.
var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
// Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
             .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('2019-11-01', '2019-11-20')
              .map(maskL8sr);

var visParams = {
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
    min: 0,
    max: 3000,
    gamma: 1.4,
};

Map.addLayer(collection.median(), visParams);

var output = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());

var thumbnail = output.getThumbURL({
    region: geometry,
    crs:'EPSG:3857',
    bands: ['B4_median', 'B3_median', 'B2_median'],
    gamma: 1.4,
    format: 'jpg',
    });

    print(thumbnail);

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: output,
  description: 'landsat', 
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  crs:'EPSG:3857',
  });
```

Comment: This is an example of a "wall of code" post. Please remember to place a description of the environment and task in the body of the question, along with a description of the problem being encountered. The title should be a summary, not the only text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) your daterange is so small that there is probably insufficient imagery to have data at every pixel location after masking. For example, extent it to about 4 months:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
              .filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-11-20')
              .map(maskL8sr);
```

2) you will have to specify a scale, min and max argument in the `getThumbURL`

```
var thumbnail = output.getThumbURL({
    region: geometry,
    crs:'EPSG:3857',
    scale: 100,               // specify
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
    gamma: 1.4,
    format: 'jpg',
    min: 0,                   // specify
    max: 3000                 // specify
    });
```

Note that I made a sample geometry as it was not shared in your code

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d2f6cb665c651bd915e722f22329244)